# R scripts that only run sequential, any way to parallelize its execution to multi cores?

Tags: linux, parallel-computing

i have some R scripts, which only can run in sequential way, cannot be broken into chunks or any parallel library for R or any other language cannot be used.

Is there any way i can distribute the Sequential execution of code to multiple cores or may be multiple servers in network? to speed up execution ?

Comment: You have said it cannot be done, but then you ask if it can be done? You have already answered your own question!

Comment: Which R implementation are you using, GNU, Microsoft, something else?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: i did not said my Script cannot do it. i said it is limitation of script, is there any way that i can run this script without doing parellelization from inside R?

Comment: If the script can only run sequentially and cannot be parallelized, then you already have your answer!

Comment: i have heard of some container, or some sort of technology, which paralelize execution of one script or program and distribute it to other cpus, cores or even network (cluster)

Comment: Can the programs all be run at the same time, or do they have dependencies on the results of previous programs?

Comment: Only workloads that can run in parallel can be parallelized! You have repeatedly said that your program cannot be parallelized. So I can't understand why you keep asking when you already know the answer!

Answer (score 0):

So let us assume you can run:

```
./my_script.R arg1
```

And you want to run the script on `arg1`..`arg1000`. Then you can use GNU Parallel:

```
parallel ./my_script.R {} ::: arg1 arg2 arg3 .. arg1000
```

This will start one `my_script.R` per CPU thread.

If you have multiple servers at your disposal that you can `ssh` to:

```
parallel -Sserver1 -Sserver2 ./my_script.R {} ::: arg1 arg2 arg3 .. arg1000
```

If this does not answer your question, please elaborate on your situation.